# Multiple strings vs array in ILIKE query with reference tables in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like

I have three tables in my schema: a main and two reference tables.
Users pass search terms (strings) in from AJAX to php to sql.

One string queries are easy.  Two or three string queries (separated by commas, turned into arrays) are much more complex... for me at least. The idea is to search and filter for those, so each return must contain **BOTH** strings.  Unfortunately that's proving difficult.  It's returning what I want, but it also returns when it's the first or second string listed **TWICE** which I don't want.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.document_id 
FROM main a 

INNER JOIN locations c 
  ON a.document_id = c.document_id 
    AND (c.street_address ILIKE any (array['%Benton%', '%Park%'])  
      OR c.location_name ILIKE any (array['%Benton%', '%Park%']) ) 

INNER JOIN names d ON a.document_id = d.document_id 
  AND (d.last_name ILIKE any (array['%Benton%', '%Park%'])  
    OR d.first_name ILIKE any (array['%Benton%', '%Park%']) ) 

  AND (a.document_id ILIKE any (array['%Benton%', '%Park%']) ) 
    OR a.title ILIKE any (array['%Benton%', '%Park%'])  
    OR a.description ILIKE ANY (array['%Benton%', '%Park%'])   

GROUP BY a.document_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 2 
ORDER BY a.document_id;
```

Is there a better method here?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "return"? And "listed twice", where? Do you want to join on locations where street_address or location_name contain BOTH words, and same for names?

Answer (score 0):

@eurotrash - your question actually gave me an idea.  The answer wasn't only in the SQL, but also in the PHP loop.  I couldn't join all the table for each query, so I had to filter which ones to search based on a hit count.  Here's my solution:

```
function searchArray($a, $b) {
    $cnt = count($a);
    $sqlArr = array();
    $lastOne = end($b);
    $valCnt = 0;
    $qArr = array();
    foreach ($b as $x => $x_value) {
        $valCnt++;
        $docCnt = $a[$x]['doccount'];
        $LocCnt = $a[$x]['loccount'];
        $PeepCnt = $a[$x]['namecount'];
        $val = pg_escape_string($x_value);
        $brac = "'%" . pg_escape_string($val) . "%'";
        $haveCnt = "";
        if ($docCnt == 0 && $LocCnt == 0 && $PeepCnt == 0) {
            return;
        }
            $haveCnt = sprintf("GROUP BY t.document_id HAVING COUNT(*) > $cnt - 1");
        $andOR = "";
        $cntZero = array_filter($a[$x], function($value) {
            return $value > 0;
        });
        $cntTheCnt = count($cntZero) >= 2 ? true : false;
        if ($cntTheCnt == false) {
            $andOR = "WHERE";
        } else {
            $andOR = "AND";
        }

        $subQuery = sprintf(" SELECT DISTINCT a$valCnt.document_id"
                . " FROM archive_main a$valCnt");

        $locJoin = sprintf(" INNER JOIN archive_locations f$valCnt"
                . " ON a$valCnt.document_id = f$valCnt.document_id");

        $locFind = sprintf(" %s f$valCnt.street_address ILIKE %s"
                . " OR f$valCnt.location_name ILIKE %s ", $andOR, $brac, $brac);

        $nameJoin = sprintf(" INNER JOIN archive_names b$valCnt"
                . " ON a$valCnt.document_id = b$valCnt.document_id");

        $nameFind = sprintf(" %s (b$valCnt.last_name ILIKE %s"
                . " OR b$valCnt.first_name ILIKE %s) ", $andOR, $brac, $brac);
        $nameFind .= "OR (FORMAT('%s %s', b$valCnt.first_name, b$valCnt.last_name) ILIKE $brac)";

        $whereDoc = sprintf(" %s a$valCnt.document_id ILIKE %s"
                . " OR a$valCnt.title ILIKE %s"
                . " OR a$valCnt.description ILIKE %s", $andOR, $brac, $brac, $brac);
        $find = "";
        $union = "";
        $joins = "";
        if ($LocCnt != 0) {
            $find .= $locFind;
            $joins .= $locJoin;
        }
        if ($PeepCnt != 0) {
            $find .= $nameFind;
            $joins .= $nameJoin;
        }
        if ($docCnt != 0) {
            $find .= $whereDoc;
        }
        if ($x_value != $lastOne) {
            $union .= sprintf(" UNION ALL ");
        } else {
            $union .= sprintf("");
        }
        array_push($qArr, $subQuery, $joins, $find, $union);
    }
    $boom = implode(' ', $qArr);
    $mainQuery = sprintf("SELECT DISTINCT t.document_id FROM (%s) as t %s
                            order by t.document_id;", $boom, $haveCnt);
    $sql = pg_query($mainQuery);
    if (!$sql) {
        $errrormsge = pg_last_error();
        print_r("$errrormsge - An error occurred during your query.");
        exit;
    }
    return($sql);
}
```

And it works well.